Sorting array of strings alphabetically (in ascendending order) in Zig
I want to sort a fruit list alphabetically in ascending order:
const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

var list = std.ArrayList([]const u8).init(allocator);
defer list.deinit();

try list.append("banana");
try list.append("apple");
try list.append("cherry");

// Sort the ArrayList alphabetically using std.mem.sort with the custom comparator
std.mem.sort([]const u8, list.items, ??, ??);

for (list.items) |item| {
    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{item});
}

I've found this std.mem.sort function in standard lib. Not sure this is the better approach for sorting lists.
Of course I can implement the algorithm from zero but I'm wondering if it's currently possible to make it done in a more "ziggy" way. I've read the std lib is not well written but I want to give it a chance. Of course I know the quicksort, but how to pass a function pointer/lambda/whatever-its-called to std.mem.sort() ? Is there anything already implemented? a template/parametric comparison function in std?
And regarding why am I allocating heap memory instead of just pushing fruits onto the stack? I'm open to use the stack, my only interest is about sorting an array of strings

std.mem.sort is the right function to use. It accepts the slice child type, the slice, "context" and "lessThanFn".
In your case, context isn't needed so we will pass "void". {} is an empty block expression and it returns a value of type void. Naming the parameter _ discards it so zig won't complain about it being unused. std.mem.order performs string comparison.
fn lessThan(_: void, lhs: []const u8, rhs: []const u8) bool {
    return std.mem.order(u8, lhs, rhs) == .lt;
}

fn sortStringSlice(slice: [][]const u8) void {
    std.mem.sort([]const u8, slice, {}, lessThan);
}

The purpose of the context parameter is for when you need additional information that is not in the lhs or rhs to determine if lhs < rhs. For example, if you were sorting indices based on their value in another array:
const Context = struct {
    values: []const []const u8
    fn lessThan(self: Context, lhs: usize, rhs: usize) bool {
        return std.mem.order(u8, self.values[lhs], self.values[rhs]) == .lt;
    }
};

fn sortIndices(indices: []usize, values: []const []const u8) void {
    const context = Context{ .values = values };
    std.mem.sort(usize, indices, context, Context.lessThan);
}


And regarding why am I allocating heap memory instead of just pushing fruits onto the stack? I'm open to use the stack, my only interest is about sorting an array of strings

Any stack memory you use must have its size known at comptime, you cannot allocate an arbitrary amount of memory on the stack.
You could have an array of fruits on the stack, but its size cannot be expanded at runtime.
var fruits: [3][]const u8 = [_][]const u8{
    "banana",
    "apple",
    "cherry",
};
std.mem.sort([]const u8, &fruits, {}, lessThan);

If you continue to use the heap, you should not be using page_allocator directly. It allocates an entire page (4kb or more) of memory for every allocation. Instead, use GeneralPurposeAllocator:
var gpa_backing = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
defer std.debug.assert(gpa_backing.deinit() == .ok);
const allocator = gpa.allocator();

